# Does MYSQL has Support for NOSQL

Tags: mysql, nosql

I want to know does mysql support nosql. i have gone through the MySQL Cluster which supports the noSQL, its very confusing. So, i want to knw whether we can integrate NoSQL with MySQL and are there any tutorials on that if possible.

Comment: Do you know what NoSQL is or are you just following the buzzword hype?

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. There are a lot of new different database concepts which do various things in various different ways, and everything they have in common are things they also have in common with traditional SQL databases.

Comment: For posterity, Combining the Power of SQL and NoSQL Databases with MySQL @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcyqU53OVnM

Answer (score 2):

> NoSQL databases are not built primarily on tables, and generally do not use SQL for data manipulation.
>
> NoSQL does not use SQL as its query language. NoSQL database systems arose alongside major Internet companies which had challenges in dealing with huge quantities of data with which conventional RDBMS solutions could not cope.

This should answer your question, since MySQL is a conventional RDBMS, uses SQL for data manipulation and it's based on tables.

**tl;dr**: No, it doesn't.

Comment: It does, but it's not easy to set up and it doesn't work with all engines. Generally, what you posted is true except there are always exceptions. I won't post into detail *how* because I hope that NoSQL hype will slowly go away so that people like OP don't spout nonsense and shoot their own foot due to lack of information.

Comment: @N.B. That's good to know (that it does support NoSQL). Or not? :D Honestly, I agree with your opinion, but mixing MySQL and NoSQL doesn't sound as something that one should do, to me...

Comment: NoSQL is a key:value store, down at the bottom. There's a way to access InnoDB's storage without using MySQL daemon. It's called HandlerSocket and googling that will give you all relevant information. InnoDB, down at the core, is an **extremely** efficient key:value memory storage engine. Which means, you can turn InnoDB into a "NoSQL". Naturally, you lose a lot in order to  gain high read speeds.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information. Another thing that I have learned today, althought I hope not to need it :)

Comment: @N.B. No, not all NoSQL databases are "key:value stores, down at the bottom". At least not more than traditional SQL databases are (primary-)key:value stores. You seem to suffer from the "NoSQL == NoSQL" preconception just as much as the OP does.

Comment: @Philipp - I have no intention to debate with a person who suffers from "I can't read and comprehend syndrome". Please, let's not continue this.

Comment: Couchbase used to use SQLite as a storage engine underneath up to version 1.8.x, but now uses a different one. How data is stored on disk is decoupled from how it's used is the point. Using JSON in MySQL can make sense but scaling it will suffer from the same challenges of scaling MySQL in general.

Comment: I have got the Answer.... MySql supports the properties of NOSQL in 2 ways.
1.Using MEMCACHED API for MYSQL (INNODB)
2.THrough MySQL CLuster (which has properties that support NOSql and MYsql)
3. SOCKET HAndler for INNODB.. which is a plugin that can enhance the mysql performance to meet the needs.. 
THis is what i wanted